Project in .Net 6 does not show results with .Netstandard 2.0 in nuget search
I created a class library in .Netstandard 2.0 and now I want to use it in .Net 6 project.
In Visual Studio 2022,when I searched for the library in the nuget manager, the library did not show up in the search but when I ran the command following command in the nuget console, it installed the library sucessfully :
 Install-Package MyClassLibPackageId -Version 1.0.1

I understand that visual studio does not show nugets that are not compatible in the search but that's not the case considering how it actually installed using command line.
My guess is that the nuget manager is not considering .Netstandard 2.0 as compatible with .Net 6 even though it is, eliminating the library from the search results.
I found two ways to solve this issue :

Install using command line
Add any .Net Framework version besides the .Netstandard 2.0 to the TargetFrameworks property of the class library project.If you do, the nuget will start showing up in the search

Even though I managed to turn around it, I would to know why this is happening.Is it an issue in nuget source server, in the visual studio or in the library?

Was the "Include Preleases" option checked in nuget manager?  If you check it, does it find the package?

I tried that but didn't work

I think you have put the package to a place that the command could scanned, but the UI and command are different in this situation, take a look of my answer. :)

The company I work in has a private nuget source and I need it work in it. Creating a local source wouln't do what I want. I used my solution number 2 for now but I still don't understand why this is happening.

I can reproduce your  situation:

Please config the path/url of where the package is to the package source configuration, and then use it in the package manager UI, then you will be able to see the package in the UI:



